# latex - fancyfoot - page count in box - colour not shown

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I'm using the following from here: http://www-ra.phys.utas.edu.au/~jstevens/code_thesis_style.html

There are also image attachments which show exactly what the following extract of code achieves.

However, the only thing that does not show up as in the pictures in the link, is that the box is not grayed. Any ideas why?

Cheers!

```
%% page nums on the bottom in a nice box
%% even side pages
\fancyfoot[LE]{\psboxit{box 0.8 setgray fill}
{\framebox[10mm][c]{\rule{0cm}{4mm}\color{black}{\bfseries \thepage}}}}
%% odd side pages
\fancyfoot[RO]{\psboxit{box 1 setgray fill}
{\hspace{\textwidth}\psboxit{box 0.8 setgray fill}
{\framebox[10mm][c]{\rule{0cm}{4mm}\color{black}{\bfseries \thepage}}}}}

%% make the bottom line above the page number box
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0mm}

%% bring the style into effect
%% (must come after all the fancyhead and fancyfoot stuff)
\pagestyle{fancy}

% now redefine the plain style pages (chapter pages, contents pages)
%% to have the same page number stuff on the bottom
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\psboxit{box 1 setgray fill}
{\hspace{\textwidth}\psboxit{box 0.8 setgray fill}
{\framebox[10mm][c]{\rule{0cm}{4mm}\color{black}{\bfseries \thepage}}}}}

\fancyfoot[LE]{\psboxit{box 0.8 setgray fill}
{\framebox[10mm][c]{\rule{0cm}{4mm}\color{black}{\bfseries \thepage}}}}


\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}
```

Comment: Make sure you compile with `latex` and `dvips`, because `\psboxit` will be ignored by `pdflatex`. Failing that, please post a minimal example, i.e. a short standalone code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I'm unable to compile to dvips, because the majority of my figures are in pdf format and dvips requires eps-formatted figures but thanks for helping ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind not using the `psboxit` package, you can achieve the same effect replacing the code snippet you posted with the code between `%start` and `%end` in the following example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to generate some text

%start
\newcommand\PageBox{%
  \raisebox{0.5pt}{\fcolorbox{black}{gray!60}{%
    \parbox[b][4mm]{10mm}{\hfil\bfseries\thepage\hfil}}}}

\fancyfoot[LE]{\PageBox}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\PageBox}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0mm}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\PageBox}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\PageBox}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
%end

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

Make sure to load the `xcolor` package in your actual document.

Comment: this worked like a charm! thank you so much! :-)